# Finding a condition to make a matrix diagonally dominant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $X$ is a real $n\times n$ matrix. $A$ is diagonally dominant (dd) if:

$$ A_{ii} \ge \sum_{j=0, j\neq i}^n |A_{ij}| \ \ \forall  i=1,2,\cdots ,n $$

Note that elements of diagonal entries should be non-negative.

Suppose $D$ is a full-rank diagonal matrix whose diagonal entries are $\pm 1$ and also $trace(D)=0$.

Suppose also $P$ is a full-rank symmetric permutation matrix such that all diagonal entries are zero.

We know if $X$ is diagonally dominant then $PXP$ and $DXD$ are also diagonally dominant.

Now, do you know any necessary or sufficient condition so that a symmetric matrix $X$ be diagonally dominant implies $(D+P)X(D+P)$ be diagonally dominant?

---

Example: For $2\times 2$ symmetric matrices $X$ be diagonally dominant always implies $(D+P)X(D+P)$ be diagonally dominant:

$$D=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix},\
P=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix},\
X=\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\ b & c \end{bmatrix}$$
$$(D+P)X(D+P)=\begin{bmatrix}a+2b+c & a-c\\ a-c & a-2b+c \end{bmatrix}$$
Therefore,
$$a \ge |b| \land c \ge |b| \Rightarrow a+c-2|b| \ge |a-c|$$

However, this is not true for higher dimensions ($n$).